# Javascript doubles export to update database

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

my code is making output to database to go on square.

For example:

- First input - 1 record
- Second input - 2 record
- Third input - 4 record
- Fourth input - 16 record...

I would need to update temperature, humidity and send date and time every couple of seconds.

```
function ZapisiVrijednosti() {

    let nDatumVrijeme = "21/03/2021 16:53"
    let nTemperatura = 23
    let nVlaznost = 70
    setInterval(function () {
        sKey = firebase.database().ref().child('ts0').push().key;
        oSenzor = {
            DatumVrijeme: nDatumVrijeme,
            Temperatura: nTemperatura,
            Vlaznost: nVlaznost
        };

        let oZapis = {};
        oZapis[sKey] = oSenzor;
        oDbsenzor0.update(oZapis);
        console.log(oZapis);
    }, 5000);
}
```

Console log after 15 seconds or 3 sessions:

```
{
  '-MWK_gQeMCF8HVBRA57s': { DatumVrijeme: '21/03/2021 16:53', Temperatura: 23, Vlaznost: 70 }
}
{
  '-MWK_he2Tr1GauEET-Oe': { DatumVrijeme: '21/03/2021 16:53', Temperatura: 23, Vlaznost: 70 }
}
{
  '-MWK_he4cLLJQzP2yC4g': { DatumVrijeme: '21/03/2021 16:53', Temperatura: 23, Vlaznost: 70 }
}
{
  '-MWK_isF8xemd1uuemim': { DatumVrijeme: '21/03/2021 16:53', Temperatura: 23, Vlaznost: 70 }
}
{
  '-MWK_isGWGMNVBEFzzOW': { DatumVrijeme: '21/03/2021 16:53', Temperatura: 23, Vlaznost: 70 }
}
{
  '-MWK_isIhxD6uywaD8Vm': { DatumVrijeme: '21/03/2021 16:53', Temperatura: 23, Vlaznost: 70 }
}
{
  '-MWK_isLdm-6yTaQcZTr': { DatumVrijeme: '21/03/2021 16:53', Temperatura: 23, Vlaznost: 70 }
}
```

If I comment out `oDbsenzor0.update(oZapis);` console.log outputs just one line every 5 seconds.

Thanks :)

Edit:

Where I call function

```
let oDb = firebase.database();
let aSenzor = [];
let oDbsenzor0 = oDb.ref('ts0');
oDbsenzor0.on('value', function (oOdgovorPosluzitelja) {
    aSenzor = [];
    oOdgovorPosluzitelja.forEach(function (oSenzorSnapshot) {
        let oSenzor = oSenzorSnapshot.val();
        aSenzor.push({
            DatumVrijeme: aSenzor.datetime,
            Temperatura: aSenzor.temperatura,
            Vlaznost: aSenzor.vlaznost
        })
    })
    ZapisiVrijednosti();
})
```

Comment: Where you call function and how?

Comment: I have edited my original post.